# Ability to programme a playground application inside same project in swift

Tags: xcode, swift-playground

The situation is as follows:

> I am trying to define a path in which a certain character travels in a game. This can be done by typing all coordinates for such path. However, this requires a lot of testing, recompiling, as you try to view such path in the product and see if it is what you wanted. This is very tedious

Clearly there is no Graphical Interface built in for every purpose, and obviously also for this case. Then, I proceed to built another application/ another few files that serve as a custom graphical interface for my path class: for editing paths by coordinates and change it interactively.

This does not really cause a problem. However, such an application does not fit in the app, nor make sense to be an application just for programming a specific class. Additionally, if I want to have an application for each of my more complicated data structures, it becomes very messy and hard to manage.

I recall that there is a playground feature in swift. This is perfect for me as it is interactive. And I am thinking:

> Is there a way to programme an playground-similar application inside the same project?

(Since I demand programming to be pretty) Can this be done without switching to different projects just for this purpose? Is there such a feature?

> Equivalently, is there a way to programme something that helps programming within swift, such as an extension for swift?

Again, I emphasis that, this is needed only for saving troubles and making an application more self-contained.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out to be a stupid question. There is obviously an option in adding a new playground file to existing project.